# Empty my Sqlite3 database in RoR

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 3 web application using sqlite3. I have been testing my application on-the-fly creating and destroying things in the Database, sometimes through the `new` and `edit` actions and sometimes through the Rails console.

I am interested in emptying my Database totally and having only the empty tables left. How can I achieve this?  I am working with a team so I am interested in two answers:
1) How do I empty the Database only by me?
2) How can I (if possible empty) it by the others (some of which are not using sqlite3 but MySql)? (we are all working on an the same project through a SVN repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by deleting the `deployment.sqlite3` file from the `db` folder and inserting the command `rake db:migrate` in the command line, it solves the problem for all of my team working on sqlite3.

Answer (score 19):

To reset your database, you can run:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Which will recreate your database from your schema.rb file (maintained by your migrations). This will additionally protect you from migrations that may later fail due to code changes.

Your dev database should be distinct to your environment - if you need certain data, add it to your seed.rb file. Don't share a dev database, as you'll quickly get into situations where other changes make your version incompatible.

Comment: This did not work for me however what is described in http://rubyunrails.blogspot.se/2010/12/clear-sqlite-database.html worked.

Answer (score 2):

Download sqlitebrower here http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Install it, run it, click open database (top left) to locationOfYourRailsApp/db/development.sqlite3

Then switch to Browse data tab, there you can delete or add data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no USER GRANT management in sqlite so it is difficult to control  access.

You only can protect the database by file access.

If you want to use an empty database for test purpose. 
Generate it once and copy the file somewhere. 
and use a copy of this file just before testing.